# C++ Program Compiling Error on Windows using MinGW32 bit compiler with Scons returns that a C++ Header file is Missing

Tags: windows-7, libraries, c++, mingw

I'm using Windows 7 SP-1 32 bit. I want to Compile Godot on my System from source.

According to the instructions, I installed Python2.x on My system. Then I installed Scons in my system too.

I used MinGW Compiler to Compile the program instead of MSVC Express Compiler.

But, I get an error that a header file audioclient.h is missing.

As far I know, Debain/Ubuntu Linux systems are easy to fix this part by just using apt and install required Library, but how to fix this issue on Windows?

Thanks

Comment: Here is the instruction to compile: http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/development/compiling/compiling_for_windows.html , you need Visual Studio.

Comment: @Biswapriyo MinGW is supposed to do everything which VS does

Comment: `audioclient.h` is part of MinGW-w64 - for 32 and 64 bit Windows. Mke sure you have that installed correctly. See [MinGW-w64 - for 32 and 64 bit Windows / mingw-w64 / \[59521d\] /mingw-w64-headers/include/audioclient.h](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/ci/59521de066fe0a7a62d541002573d464d46129e1/tree/mingw-w64-headers/include/audioclient.h)